# Disable weekends as Friday & Sturday for Jquery DatePicker

Tags: jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui-datepicker

I am working on ASP.net Webform application where i need to block certain dates and Weekend as Friday & Saturday.

Following Code works fine, It block the dates but by default blocks Saturday & Sunday as weekend while i need to block all Fridays & Saturdays on calendar.

I would appreciate fix to this particular code. I am not sure if jQuery Calendar has a built-in property to specify different weekends

```
var holiDays = [[2012, 07, 06, 'New Years Day'], [2012, 07, 14, 'Event XYZ'], [2011, 17, 25, 'Christmas Day']];
$(function () {
    $("#<%=txtBookDate.ClientID %>").datepicker({
        dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
        minDate: "-0d",
        maxDate: "+60d",
        beforeShowDay: noWeekendsOrHolidaysOrBlockedDates
    });

    function noWeekendsOrHolidaysOrBlockedDates(date) {
        var noWeekend = jQuery.datepicker.noWeekends(date);
        return noWeekend[0] ? setHoliDays(date) : noWeekend;
    }

    // set holidays function which is configured in beforeShowDay
    function setHoliDays(date) {
        for (i = 0; i < holiDays.length; i++) {
            if (date.getFullYear() == holiDays[i][0]
  && date.getMonth() == holiDays[i][1] - 1
  && date.getDate() == holiDays[i][2]) {
                return [false, 'holiday', holiDays[i][3]];
            }
        }
        return [true, ''];
    }


});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you not have access to the jQuery UI source? Odd, because it is javascript, and usually freely available:

```
/* Set as beforeShowDay function to prevent selection of weekends.
   @param  date  Date - the date to customise
   @return [boolean, string] - is this date selectable?, what is its CSS class? */
noWeekends: function(date) {
    var day = date.getDay();
    return [(day > 0 && day < 6), ''];
}
```

Looks pretty well non-customizable, but relatively easy to reimplement as your own function.

Comment: Appreciate you reply, I don't want to edit the main source file, as i want the to do it through script as mentioned in the question.. How exactly should i use part of your code example on jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Pt2Mr/404/

Comment: @KnowledgeSeeker - just place similar code in the top of your `setHolidays` function: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Nakqq/1/)